# How to read numbers in python conveniently?

Tags: python

```
x1, y1, a1, b1, x2, y2 = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
```

My problem is to read 6 numbers each given on a new line. How to do that more laconically than my code above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x1, y1, a1, b1, x2, y2 = (int(input()) for _ in range(6))
```

Replace `range` with `xrange` and `input` with `raw_input` in Python 2.

Comment: In python2, you don't need `int` unless you replace `input()` with `raw_input()`  -- which you definitely should ...

Answer (score 1):

```
x,y,z,w=map(int,input().split()) #add input in form 1 2 3 4


>>> x,y,z,w=map(int,input().split()) 
1 2 3 4
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> w
4
>>> z
3
```

Comment: numbers are not given in one line :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use dictionaries:

```
parm = {}
var_names = ['x1', 'y1', 'a1', 'b1', 'x2', 'y2']
for var_name in var_names:
    parm[var_name] = int(input())
```

then you can transform dictionary keys into variables, but I do not think it is a good idea:

```
locals().update(parm)
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify the dict returned by `vars()` since it is the same as `locals()` which has an explicit warning in the docs against this.  You could use `globals().update(parm)` if you want to write bad code the right way though ...